# Increase the height of collectionview cell on button press and scroll to bottom

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view controller implemented with the following method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 661)
}
```

I have hardcoded a height value but when I press a button I want the height of the cell to be 800 and scrolled to bottom of cell.( I just have one cell). Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dynamicHeight = 661
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: dynamicHeight )
}
@IBAction func yourButton(_ sender: Any?)
{
   self.dynamicHeight = 800
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```